¿Cómo habilitar la generación del método toString en jdtls para Neovim cuando la clase tiene atributos?
Estoy usando Neovim con jdtls (Eclipse JDT Language Server) para el desarrollo en Java. Aunque la mayoría de las funcionalidades funcionan bien, tengo un problema específico con la generación del método toString.
Lo que he intentado:
He configurado jdtls en Neovim usando nvim-lspconfig.
Puedo ver y usar otras acciones de código sin problemas.
He intentado colocar el cursor dentro de la clase y usar :lua vim.lsp.buf.code_action(), pero no aparece la opción para generar el método toString cuando la clase tiene atributos.
Observación:
Cuando la clase no tiene atributos, la opción para generar el método toString sí aparece. Sin embargo, cuando la clase ya tiene atributos definidos, dicha opción no se muestra.
Aquí está la parte relevante de mi configuración de jdtls en lua:
            { filetypes = {
            "java",
        },
        cmd = {
            "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.21.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java",
            "-Declipse.application=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.id1",
            "-Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4",
            "-Declipse.product=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.product",
            "-Dlog.protocol=true",
            "-Dlog.level=ALL",
            "-Xms1g",
            "--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM",
            "--add-opens",
            "java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED",
            "--add-opens",
            "java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED",
            "-javaagent:" .. jdtls_path .. "/lombok.jar",
            "-jar",
            vim.fn.glob(jdtls_path .. "/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_*.jar"),
            "-configuration",
            jdtls_path .. "/config_" .. os_config,
            "-data",
            workspace_dir,
        },
        root_dir = require("lspconfig.server_configurations.jdtls").default_config.root_dir,
        settings = {
            java = {
                eclipse = {
                    downloadSources = true,
                },
                configuration = {
                    updateBuildConfiguration = "interactive",
                    runtimes = {
                        {
                            name = "JavaSE-21",
                            path = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.21.0-openjdk-amd64",
                        },
                    },
                },
                maven = {
                    downloadSources = true,
                },
                implementationsCodeLens = {
                    enabled = true,
                },
                referencesCodeLens = {
                    enabled = true,
                },
                references = {
                    includeDecompiledSources = true,
                },
                inlayHints = {
                    parameterNames = {
                        enabled = "all", -- literals, all, none
                    },
                },
                format = {
                    enabled = true,
                },
                codeGeneration = {
                    generateComments = false,
                    useBlocks = true,
                    toString = {
                        codeStyle = "STRING_CONCATENATION",
                        -- listArrayContents = true,
                        template = "${object.className} [${member.name()}=${member.value}, ${otherMembers}]",
                        -- limitElements = 10
                    },
                    hashCodeEquals = {
                        useInstanceof = true,
                        useJava7Objects = true,
                    },
                },
                codeAction = {
                    sortMembers = {
                        avoidVolatileChanges = true
                    }
                }
            },
            signatureHelp = { enabled = true },
        },
        init_options = {
            bundles = {
                java_debug_path .. "/extension/server/com.microsoft.java.debug.plugin-0.50.0.jar",
                vim.fn.glob(java_test_path .. "/extension/server/com.microsoft.java.debug.plugin-*.jar", 1),
            },
        },
        on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
            local _, _ = pcall(vim.lsp.codelens.refresh)
            require("jdtls.dap").setup_dap({ hotcodereplace = "auto" })
            require("jdtls.dap").setup_dap_main_class_configs()
            require("vim.lsp").on_attach(client, bufnr)
            -- local status_ok, jdtls_dap = pcall(require, "jdtls.dap")
            -- if status_ok then
            -- jdtls_dap.setup_dap_main_class_configs()
            -- end
        end,
    }

¡Cualquier orientación o solución sería muy apreciada!
